# How to update package name for Play Store app bundle?

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

I followed [the steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502832/how-to-sign-flutter-app-bundle-in-order-to-publish-it-to-play-store) to sign bundle for my Flutter app.

Than I dragged `build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab` to Google Play console's app bundles, and got error `You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.`

I searched for "com.example" in my project folder, but did not find anything.

Where can I update the package name?

[image: error]

Comment: What package name is in `android>app>build.gradle>defaultConfig>applicationId`.  In the official guide scroll down to [Reviewing the Gradle build configuration](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change package name in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change package name in android you need to use this command in your terminal

```
flutter pub global activate rename
```

then

```
rename setBundleId --value "com.your.package.name"
```

Answer (score 3):

**android -> app -> build.gradle**[image]

make sure when using any package name you need to change

> example

, because Google not support example keword so instead of example give any name like

```
"com.bijoy.bijoyx"
```

Answer (score 2):

add this :

```
dependencies:
  change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
```

then in the terminal write this :

```
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name
```

change **com.new.package.name** with your **name**

Comment: Cool! I assume it can be in dev_dependencies too.