# How do I sign an Android Flutter app for release?

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

I'm not looking to sign it for upload to the Play Console. I want control over the release signing.
Unfortunately everything I search talks about setting up signing for uploading to the Play Console, but I want to sign the app for upload AND release myself and not let Google sign it for release.

Comment: Hope This Answers Your Question [Detailed Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502832/how-to-sign-flutter-app-bundle-in-order-to-publish-it-to-play-store)

Comment: No, this is for the upload key.

Comment: did you published the app first version yet ? if yes, then you can not do it , if not ,reply...

Comment: @NAZIRHUSSAIN No

Answer (score -1):

If you want to sign and release an APK, you can do either of the two:

**Method 1:**

1. Open the android folder in your project with Android Studio
2. Menu > Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK > APK
3. Create key if you don't have yet, otherwise select the key and fill up the alias and passwords
4. Select release, and create
5. You will be notified on the side once the build is done. There should be a clickable text from the notification that will open your file explorer to show where the APK is located.

**Method 2:**

1. Do the same steps #2 and #3 from Method 1 (to create the key)
2. Create key.properties file inside android folder
3. Add keyAlias, keyPassword, storePassword, storeFile, and their corresponding values
4. Ensure that it's defined in your build.gradle (android/app/build.gradle)
5. Run flutter build apk --release
6. Once done, the APK file will be found in (project_folder\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk)

I've added a screenshot below for your reference
[image]

EDIT [02/20/2024]
For reference, this is what you should be seeing in the build menu
[image]

Comment: I already have the signing config, but Google still signs the bundle themselves. Although I do not have the v1 & v2 args, are those actually needed or just legacy stuff ?

Comment: Additionally, there is no "Generate Signed Bundle/APK" in the build menu when in the Android project.

Comment: If you don't see the "Generate Signed Bundle/APK" in the build menu; there's probably something else wrong. Because when you open the android folder (with Android Studio) inside the flutter project and let gradle finish its thing (building or compiling stuff); that should be visible

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what you should be seeing in the build menu if you've opened the android folder in your flutter project.

Comment: Alright, so apparently the option isn't visible is the gradle build fails. I hate it when options are hidden instead of greyed out... Devs ; please grey out your options and have the hover info say why it's greyed out. Don't hide it and cause confusion.